# How do I stop my Sony ATV from starting when I use my DVD Player connected to it?

Tags: android-tv, sony

I am using a Sony KD-49XF8505 Android TV. When I put a CD into the external media player to listen to music with the sound system connected to it, the TV automatically starts up and switches to the HDMI port the DVD player is connected to. How can I stop the TV from turning on when I only want to listen to music? Is there any setting for that? Since I do not have an idea of where to start looking, I have not tried anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a setting of the Bravia Sync feature included in most Android TVs, the option to toggle this behavior on and off can be found under `Settings > External Inputs > Bravia Sync Settings > Auto TV on`. This way you should be able to use your external device independently of your TV.